# iList to gridview (Select HQL)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nhibernate

I have the select in HQL:

```
 Dim query As IQuery = sessao.CreateQuery("SELECT PS.PseObs, P.PacNome " +
                                           "FROM PacientesServicos AS PS INNER JOIN PS.Pacientes AS P " +
                                           "INNER JOIN  PS.Servicos AS S " +
                                           "INNER JOIN  PS.Usuarios AS U " +
                                           "WHERE PS.Pacientes.PacNome like :nome")

                         query.SetParameter("nome", "HA%")
                         query.SetMaxResults(5)
 Dim Listagem As IList = query.List
 Return Listagem
```

I don't know to put this list in gridview.datasource. I try to modify columns the gridview, but not found datafield. Is name property different when I use select with property other objects? But when I remove SELECT I can to put in gridview.datasource.

...

```
  <asp:templatefield headertext="Pacientes">
                            <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:label id="Id"
                                Text= '<%# Eval("Pacientes.PacNome") %>'
                                runat="server"/> 
                            </itemtemplate>
                            </asp:templatefield>
  <asp:boundfield headertext="Observações" datafield="PseObs" ControlStyle-Width = "600" />
```

Please, I need to help. I don't know.
I want to get Ilist and to put in gridview.datasource directly,

I need to idea.

Comment: Have you tried <%# Eval("PacNome") %>

Answer (score 0):

I created a class with constructor.
My HQL bellow:

```
                 Dim query As IQuery = sessao.CreateQuery("SELECT New Teste(P.PacNome,PS.PseObs) " +
                                                         "FROM PacientesServicos AS PS INNER JOIN PS.Pacientes AS P " +
                                                         "INNER JOIN  PS.Servicos AS S " +
                                                         "INNER JOIN  PS.Usuarios AS U " +
                                                         "WHERE PS.Pacientes.PacNome like :nome")

                query.SetParameter("nome", "HALL%")

                Dim Listagem As IList(Of Teste) = query.List(Of Teste)()
```

**Created class Teste:**

```
Public Class Teste


    Private nome_ As String
    Private obs_ As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal nome As String, ByVal obs As String)
        Me.nome_ = nome
        Me.obs_ = obs
    End Sub

    Public Property Nome As String
        Get
            Return nome_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            nome_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Obs As String
        Get
            Return obs_
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            obs_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

End Namespace

**And I Had to create teste.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  assembly="Modelo" namespace="Modelo.Cidadania.Modelo" >   <import class="Teste"/> </hibernate-mapping>
```